# How to save frontend user login/registeration intomation in django project

Tags: django

Am new to django. Any one could suggest me, How to handle frontend user in django project. Such as how and where to save frontend information like first name, last name, email id. Should i create new table in db or save this infomation in admin user table.

Sorry for me bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The base user model can handle this. [Docs here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/) It also comes with some useful built-in forms to help users register - [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i need some custom functionality for ex: i don't need is staff, permissions, group. so can i use User for my forntend user. I need some custom fields in table.